# assigning a piped command to the variable batch

Tags: batch-file, variables

I'm having trouble assigning a command that counts the number of times a file in a directory appears to a variable.
I found that I should do this - `(^ |)` but when I do it and echo the variable, nothing is displayed, and there should be a number of occurrences.

My code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b C:\Users\AD10FC\IdeaProjects\collateral\db-resources\release | findstr /B "!first%!-" | find /c /v ""') do set VAR=%%i

echo %VAR%
```

Comment: It's `^|`, not `^ |`.

Comment: What do you mean by `!first%!` – should it be `%first%`, or `!first!`? if the latter, add `EnableDelayedExpansion` to the `setlocal` command…

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `findstr.exe` in your code to filter the leading strings, because you can filter those directly in `Dir`:

```bsh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "first=LeadingString"
For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('"Dir /B /A:-D "%UserProfile%\IdeaProjects\collateral\db-resources\release\%first%-*" | "%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe" /V /C """') Do Set "VAR=%%G"
Echo(%VAR%
Pause
```

Also for the specific task you're performing, you may find the following works better for you:

```bsh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "first=LeadingString"
For /F %%G In ('""%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe" "%UserProfile%\IdeaProjects\collateral\db-resources\release\%first%-*" . /LQH"') Do Set "VAR=%%G"
Echo(%VAR%
Pause
```